# TokenInput + Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-tokeninput

I want to create a textbox with pre-defined possible values but I ended up with getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

I try to use Token Input script (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) but I failed to read data from the database. I'm working with .NET MVC.

Here's my method (in Model) to read data:

```
   public List<CRMClientsModel> CRMClientsModel() {   
        var sqlConnect = DbConnectHelper.GetDbInstance<SqlConnection>();
        var query = string.Format("SELECT CompanyName,Id from Company");
        return sqlConnect.Query<CRMClientsModel>(query).ToList();
   }
```

And here the part of controller responsible for conversion of data to JSON format

```
        CRMLogic Logic = new CRMLogic();
        CRMModel Model = new CRMModel();
        List<CRMClientsModel> Clients = Logic.CRMClientsModel().ToList();
        List<CRMClientViewModel> ClientsVM = Clients.Select(a => a.ToViewModel<CRMClientViewModel>()).ToList();
        Model.CRMClientsModel = Clients;
        CRMViewModel ViewModel = new CRMViewModel();
        ViewModel.CRMClientsModel = ClientsVM;

        JavaScriptSerializer jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(ClientsVM);

        ViewModel.jsonproject = json;
```

Then in View it's called by

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).ready(function () {
        @*var item = @Html.Raw(Model.jsonproject)
            alert(item)*@
        $("#inputproject").tokenInput(@Html.Raw(Model.jsonproject),
        {
            theme: "facebook", minChars: 0
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It turned out that the error was caused by missing "propertyToSearch". Similar issue below:
[jQuery-tokeninput failing: "term" is undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045622/jquery-tokeninput-failing-term-is-undefined)